# Why is my recyclerview overlapping a part of my layout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a Layout and a Recyclerview. The layout should be a searchbar an always overlap my recyclerview like this:

[image]

But it Looks like this:

[image]

This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:foreground="#000"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/searchbar_layout"
        android:layout_height="58dp">
    </LinearLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:id="@+id/my_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I don't know the, because only a small part of my recyclcerview overlaps the searchbar and not the whole.

**How can I make my layout looking like the first Image**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/searchbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:foreground="#000"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></LinearLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/searchbar_layout" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

1. Copy this code
2. Open .xml file
3. Press CTRL+A to select all the code
4. Press delete button
5. Now press CTRL+V

Issue will be resolved

Comment: You do not use this (app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/searchbar_layout") line in xml tag of recyclerview code. try this. Thanks

Comment: Try explaining the solution you proposed. What is the problem and how you solve it. I see that you mentioned in a comment section, but it would be much better if you include them in your answer

Answer (score 0):

By default, [sibling views will be drawn in the order they appear in the tree](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#drawing), so your RecyclerView will be drawn after your LinearLayout, which results in your RecyclerView overlaps your LinearLayout.

The reason why only part of your LinearLayout get overlapped is because RecyclerView have a transparent background.

Move your RecyclerView before LinearLayout will resolve this problem, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:id="@+id/my_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:foreground="#000"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/searchbar_layout"
        android:layout_height="58dp">
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

another way to modify Z-order is to use android:elevation, elevation will also give you a shadow if you [meet some conditions](https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping#Shadows), but elevation only works on Android 5.0 and up.

Note: You should give every child of ConstraintLayout a constraint, like what @moon do.
To know more about ConstraintLayout, you can visit here: https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout